# Question About The C++ Programming Language

Tags: c++, inheritance

In Chapter 24.3.4 of the book *The C++ Programming Language* it said that

> ```
> class Cfield : public Field{ /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> This expresses the notion that a
>   `Cfield` really is a kind of Field,
>   allows notational convenience when
>   writing a `Cfield` function that uses a
>   member of the Field part of the
>   `Cfield`, and - most importantly -
>   allows a `Cfield` to override Field
>   virtual functions. **The snag is that
>   the `Cfield*` to `Field*` conversion
>   implied in the declaration of `Cfield`
>   defeats all attempts to control access
>   to the `Field`:**
>
> ```
> void g(Cfield* p)
> {
>     *p = "asdf"; // access to Field controlled by Cfield's assignment operator:
>                  // p->Cfield::operator=("asdf")
>
>     Field* q = p; // implicit Cfield* to Field* conversion
>     *q = "asdf"   // OOPS! no control
> }
> ```

What I DO NOT understand here, is the bolded sentence. How did `Cfield` defeat the attempt to control access to `Field`?

Actually, the last line of the code:

```
*q = "asdf";
```

will call `Field::operator=("asdf")`, so how did `Cfield` defeat the attempt to control access to `Field`?

Comment: If the operator= is declared virtual, it will call `CField::operator=`

Comment: What does "Chapter 24.3.4" refer to? Is it a book, is it a plane?

Comment: Which book of Chapter 24.3.4?

Comment: @Fredrik @Gunner "The C++ Programming Language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give a concrete example:

```
struct Field {
  Field(char const* s): string(s) {}
  char const* string;
};

struct CField: Field {
  CField(char const* s): Field(s), length(s ? ::strlen(s) : 0) {}
  std::size_t length;
};
```

This is a very basic kind of string, that does not allow modification of the string it refers too. `CField` augments the `Field` class by caching the length of the string.

Now, in action:

```
void foo(CField& cf) {  // 0
  cf = "foo";           // 1

  Field& f = cf;        // 2
  f = "foobar";         // 3
}
```

What happens ?

- line 0: state is unknown
- line 1: call to `CField& CField::operator=(CField const&)`, which creates a temporary `CField` (using the constructor), `cf.string` is `"foo"` and `cf.length` is `3`
- line 2: same object, access via `Field` directly
- line 3: call to `Field& Field::operator=(Field const&)`, which creates a temporary `Field` (using the constructor), `cf.string` is `"foobar"` and `cf.length` is `3` (unchanged)

As you can note, the invariant that `length` caches the length of the `string` is broken because of the unprotected access to `string` via `Field&`.

Answer (score 4):

`CField` instances are supposed to provide controlled (i.e. checked in some way by `CField::operator=()` ) access to the `Field` base class data. But if you implicitly cast a `CField *` to a `Field *`, that and then dereference it, that control is gone because you pick up `Field::operator=()`.

I agree that this is not the clearest of BS's writings, and seems to me to be a bit of a none-issue - you can always get "uncontrolled access" to anything if you put your mind to it.

Comment: But here you can get the "uncontrolled access" by mistake by just passing the object to another function. Guess this is some kind of argument against public inheritence.

Comment: @Bo That is one of the points BS makes later in the section. I just can't get very excited about it myself, and in fact I don't think reducing the access of a base in derived classes is a good idea.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, I think BS's meaning is I can't get access to Filed, becasue I can only get access to Cfield, but the code didn't run that way.

Comment: @shengy No, that isn't what he meant.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth is there any possible that BS forgot or defaulted the operator=() function is virtual, that will make sence.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth still can't get the real meaning, could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it refers to the problem that the assignment operator of `Cfield` might do special things that are required to keep the state of the object consistent. By using the assignment operator of the superclass, invariants might be broken.